# How to gather all cookies using CEFSharp?

Tags: cefsharp

In order to do a download using WebClient not Chrome, I intercepted a download URL. Then I had problems fetching cookies using a **visitor**. The pitfall I fell in was that I did not understand that the visitor is running asynchronously and therefore only in 30% of the cases got the correct result accessing the collected cookies too early.

As I search quite long for a solution I would like to paste the one I found in the demo code here.

Answer (score 6):

This is the code I found. The **await** key word is the vital piece I was missing:

```cs
class CookieCollector : ICookieVisitor
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<List<Cookie>> _source = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Cookie>>();

    public bool Visit(Cookie cookie, int count, int total, ref bool deleteCookie)
    {
        _cookies.Add(cookie);

        if (count == (total - 1))
        {
            _source.SetResult(_cookies);
        }

    }

    // https://github.com/amaitland/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/ce6e579ad77dc92be94c0129b4a101f85e2fd75b/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/ListCookieVisitor.cs
    // CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms ListCookieVisitor 

    public Task<List<Cookie>> Task => _source.Task;

    public static string GetCookieHeader(List<Cookie> cookies)
    {

        StringBuilder cookieString = new StringBuilder();
        string delimiter = string.Empty;

        foreach (var cookie in cookies)
        {
            cookieString.Append(delimiter);
            cookieString.Append(cookie.Name);
            cookieString.Append('=');
            cookieString.Append(cookie.Value);
            delimiter = "; ";
        }

        return cookieString.ToString();
    }

    private readonly List<Cookie> _cookies = new List<Cookie>();
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

// usage:
void foo()
{
    var cookieManager = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
    var visitor = new CookieCollector();

    cookieManager.VisitUrlCookies(targetUrl, true, visitor);

    var cookies = await visitor.Task; // AWAIT !!!!!!!!!
    var cookieHeader = CookieCollector.GetCookieHeader(cookies);
}
```

Comment: Were you experiencing problems with the built in `VisitAllCookiesAsync` method? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/11dee93bf331f012dd6416fb2f2162549d9137a3/CefSharp/ICookieManager.cs#L54

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The app waits and waits on the statement "var cookies = await visitor.Task;" and never completes. I'm using CefSharp version 47.

Answer (score 0):

For the first you should implement a class based on `ICookieVisitor` interface like below:

```
public class CookiesVisitor : ICookieVisitor
{
    private readonly List<Cookie> cookies = new List<Cookie>();
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<List<Cookie>> source = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Cookie>>();
    public void Dispose() { }

    public bool Visit(Cookie cookie, int count, int total, ref bool deleteCookie)
    {
        cookies.Add(cookie);

        if (count == (total - 1)) source.SetResult(cookies);

        return true;
    }

    public Task<List<Cookie>> Task => source.Task;

    public static string GetCookieHeader(List<Cookie> cookies) =>
        string.Join("; ",from cookie in cookies select string.Join("=", cookie.Name, cookie.Value));

}
```

Then get the cookies with which one of these ways:

```
    public System.Net.CookieContainer GetCookieContainer(params string[] targets)
    {
        var lc = GetCookies(targets, 2);
        if (lc == null) return null;
        var cs = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        foreach (var c in lc)
            cs.Add(new System.Net.Cookie(c.Name,c.Value,c.Path,c.Domain));
        return cs;
    }

    public System.Net.CookieContainer GetCookieContainer(string[] targets, int secondsLimit)
    {
        var lc = GetCookies(targets, secondsLimit);
        if (lc == null) return null;
        var cs = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        foreach (var c in lc)
            cs.Add(new System.Net.Cookie(c.Name, c.Value, c.Path, c.Domain));
        return cs;
    }

    public List<Cookie> GetCookies(params string[] targets)
    {
        return GetCookies(targets,2);
    }

    public List<Cookie> GetCookies(string[] targets, int secondsLimit)
    {
        List<Cookie> lc = new List<Cookie>();
        foreach (var target in targets)
        {
            var visitor = GetCookiesAsync(target);
            if (visitor.Wait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, secondsLimit)))
                lc.AddRange(visitor.Result);
        }
        return lc.Count == 0? null: lc;
    }

    public async Task<List<Cookie>> GetCookiesAsync(string target)
    {
        var cookieManager = CefSharp.Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
        var visitor = new CookiesVisitor();

        cookieManager.VisitUrlCookies(target, true, visitor);

        return await visitor.Task;
    }
```

Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

using the visitor is still async, the easiest way I found is to wrap the async function using a task:

Task<List<CefSharp.Cookie>> task = Task.Run<List<CefSharp.Cookie>>(async () => await m_CookieManager.VisitUrlCookiesAsync(url + "/", true));

then

task.Result will have the List<CefSharp.Cookie>