# CefSharp synchronous VisitCookies

Tags: vb.net, winforms, chromium, cefsharp

Is there a way to make CefSharp's cookie visitor synchronous?

For example, when doing

```
Private Sub btn1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    Dim CookieGrabber = New Cefsharp_CookieVisitor 'Implementation of ICookieVisitor
    CefSharp.Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager().VisitUrlCookies(BaseURL, True, CookieGrabber)
    Dim test = CookieGrabber
End Sub
```

I get empty results in my test variable. It does get set, but only like 2 seconds later. So everything works, but the timing is not right so I would like to make it synchronous or await completion somehow.

I tried things, but they didn't work.
For example [How to gather all cookies using CEFSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690273/how-to-gather-all-cookies-using-cefsharp) the ui gets frozen even though completion should be called.

Comment: There is an extension method that wraps the call in an `async` fashion, see http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_AsyncExtensions_VisitUrlCookiesAsync.htm Calling in a `sync` fashion is not supported.

Comment: Well the one I described in op is also async, but with this it works just like sync simply calling AsyncExtensions.VisitUrlCookiesAsync(CookieManager, BaseURL, True).Result and i get them properly and at proper time. Thanks.

Comment: Calling it in a `sync` fashion as you are suggesting may work in some cases, it is however not supported, if you experience any problems you will need to rewrite your code as `async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling AsyncExtensions.VisitUrlCookiesAsync(CookieManager, BaseURL, True).Result served the purpose so I'm closing this question.